# Data Extraction when hazard ratio is shown by Log-transformed independent variable

Tags: meta-analysis

How can we know the hazard ratio per unit of the independent variable when the data are gine by log2 change (or double increase) in the independent variable?

For instance, for each double increase in the epicardial adipose tissue volume the hazard ratio for coronary events is 1.54 (1.09; 2.19). What is the HR por 1 unit (or 10 units) change in the fat volume? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a little hard to follow. Can you make this more concrete, somehow? Eg, maybe you have some output you can paste in?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=mahabadi+A+association+of+epicardial+fat+and+cardiovascular+risk+factors+and+incident+myocardial+infarction

Comment: I intent to extract the data from table 3 of the paper in the link above. The authors showed the hazard ratio per double increase in the independent variable. I need to know which is the hazard ratio per unit change of independent variable. Thank you much for help.

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: In a model where the independent variable is the epicardial adipose tissue volume (continuous variable), and the dependent variable is the incidence of myocardial infarction, if the author give the hazard ratio per double increase of epicardial fat, which is the hazard ratio per 1 unit (or 10 units) of epicardial fat?

Comment: Please use the "edit" button underneath your question to update it with new information, rather trying to post clarifications in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The short but unhelpful answer is that you cannot do what you want from the published table as they are using $\log(X)$ and you want $X$ and there is no simple way to convert between them. You could try writing to the authors and asking if they still have the data accessible and if they will re-analyse it to give you the information you need for your review but otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The epicardial fat volumes ranged from 13 to 390 milliliters (ml) in the cited publication. With a wide range and a skew in the distribution of fat volumes the authors looked for changes in hazard related to proportional changes (log-unit changes, here $log_2$) in fat volumes.

If the increased hazard is truly related to the proportional change in fat volume, then the increased hazard per 10 ml will be a good deal different if you start with low fat volume rather than a high fat volume. You could prepare a table that relates hazard per extra 10 ml of fat as a function of initial fat volume, by determining the number of $log_2$ units corresponding to a 10-ml increase in volume over the range of initial volumes, and multiplying those numbers of units by the coefficient reported for $log_2$-unit changes.

The authors should be willing to share the data underlying their published results, in a form that does not identify individuals. So as @mdewey suggests you could then try to repeat their analysis using fat volume on a linear rather than a log scale, along with the other covariates (which seem to explain a good deal of the single-variable relation of fat volume to outcome).

My guess, however, is that the authors already tried that and that there wasn't a good relation of fat volume on a linear scale to outcome in the Cox analysis. There is usually a good deal of initial data exploration to find the best way to present results. In principle, such initial exploration should be incorporated into statistical significance tests. In practice, it almost never is.